# Rails / Passenger / Nginx: "Missing encryption key to decrypt file with"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, passenger-nginx

I have a Rails 6 app served by Passenger/Nginx.

I just rebooted a (working) server and now get the error:

```
Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /home/deployer/releases/20201114191912/config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].
```

However, I *do* provide the master key via the `ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']` in the Nginx vhost configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my_site` (which has always worked in the past):

```
server {
    listen               443  ssl;
    listen               [::]:443  ssl;
    server_name          www.my_site.com;

    passenger_env_var     RAILS_MASTER_KEY  4f9b18f1...f7cf2e0545;

    [...]
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to make it work again?

The command responsible is:

```
/usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb
```

The remaining error stack trace is:

```
App 2214 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: exit (SystemExit)
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:60:in `exit'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:60:in `rescue in block in <class:Railtie>'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:56:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/releases/20201115171757/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
App 2214 output:     config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
App 2214 output:     config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in `instance_eval'
App 2214 output:     /home/deployer/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in `initialize'
App 2214 output:     config.ru:1:in `new'
App 2214 output:     config.ru:1:in `<main>'
App 2214 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
App 2214 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
App 2214 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
App 2214 output:     /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:378:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
App 2214 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
App 2214 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 2214 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[ E 2020-11-15 17:18:26.6435 658/Tt age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deployer/current
```

Comment: maybe there are 2 spaces in env declaration? `RAILS_MASTER_KEY(here)  4f9b18f1...f7cf2e0545;`

Comment: @nuaky - Thanks! There _were_ 2 spaces in the declaration. When I set it to 1 space, everything worked again. Strangely, when I set it to 2 or more spaces again, everything still worked (again). Weird... but thanks!